# OSX: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, macos, ld

I'm helping a friend test hiis code on OSX but when I get to linking I get this error:

```
Linking CXX executable rme
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "BrowseTileWindow::BrowseTileWindow(wxWindow*, Map const*, Tile*, wxPoint)", referenced from:
      MapCanvas::OnBrowseTile(wxCommandEvent&) in map_display.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [rme] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/rme.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm not even sure what part of the code is producing the error but from what I understand it domes from these two areas:

I'm not sure if the code here is what is mentioned in the error but I cant find that specific line in the code(this code is in a new .cpp file):

```
BrowseTileWindow::BrowseTileWindow(wxWindow* parent, const Map* map, Tile* tile, wxPoint position /* = wxDefaultPosition */) :
    wxDialog(parent, wxID_ANY, "Browse Field", position, wxSize(600, 400), wxCAPTION | wxCLOSE_BOX | wxRESIZE_BORDER)
    {
     wxSizer* sizer = newd wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
     item_list = newd BrowseTileListBox(this, wxID_ANY, tile);
     sizer->Add(item_list, wxSizerFlags(1).Expand());

     wxString pos;
     pos << wxT("x=") << tile->getX() << wxT(", y=") << tile->getY() << wxT(", z=") << tile->getZ();

     wxSizer* infoSizer = newd wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
     infoSizer->Add(newd wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("Position: ") + pos), wxSizerFlags(0).Center());
     infoSizer->Add(newd wxStaticText(this, wxID_ANY, wxT("Item count: ") + i2ws(item_list->GetItemCount())), wxSizerFlags(0).Left());
     sizer->Add(infoSizer, wxSizerFlags(0).Center().DoubleBorder());

     SetSizerAndFit(sizer);
    }
```

Referenced from map_display.cpp(this is the code that was added):

```
void MapCanvas::OnBrowseTile(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
    {
     if (editor.selection.size() != 1)
     return;

     Tile* tile = editor.selection.getSelectedTile();
     if (!tile) return;
     ASSERT(tile->isSelected());

     wxDialog* w = new BrowseTileWindow(gui.root, &editor.map, tile, wxPoint(cursor_x, cursor_y));
     w->ShowModal();
     w->Destroy();
    }
```

I know this has been asked any times before here on this site but I just cant find anything that will solve my problem. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling and linking the new .cpp file (the one that contains `BrowseTileWindow::BrowseTileWindow`) ?

Comment: well, the error is pretty clear: it cannot find the class/method you're calling. Can you make it so you have the full clang command appearing (either by editing the makefile or passing a verbose option to it), and then taking that last clang command, and execute with `-v`, and paste the result in your post? The typical problems are either that you're not compiling the class where the object is defined, or the order of compilation is linking the objects in wrong order, making the user need the used, before the used has been linked.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751868/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-compiling-problems

Comment: Searching for "StackOverflow c++ 86_64" yielded a bunch of answers that may help you.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews not sure this is the right duplicate, there's still two possibilities here.. It can be linking order, wait for precisions to decide what it is a duplicate of! But for sure it's a duplicate! ;-)

Comment: Thanks alot. It was a stupid mistake on my side because I forgot to include the files in the CMakeLists.txt.