# Another one: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: c++

I have been looking through all of the different "Undefined symbol" posts, but I still can't get my particular situation to work. I originally received the undefined error when compiling my greater project, but even when I localize it just to the specific class, I am still getting the errors. I am pretty new to C++ to I feel there is some greater concept on how the compiler and linkers work in C++. I wasn't sure how much of my code to include, but let me know if what I included was excessive. So now for the code:

my header file

```
#ifndef FCFS_H
#define FCFS_H

#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <Process.h>

using namespace std;

class FCFS{

public:
        /* Simple Constructor */

        FCFS(){
                totWaitTime = 0;
                totTurnAround = 0;
                timeElapsed = 0;
                vectorSize = 0;
        }

        /* Simple Accessors */
        inline int returnTotWT() const {return totWaitTime;}
        inline int returnTotTAT() const {return totTurnAround;}
        inline int returnTime() const {return timeElapsed;}
        inline int returnVecSize() const {return vectorSize;}

        /* Mutators */
        void buildMatrix(ifstream& myinfile);
        Process buildProcess(string line);
        vector<string>parser (const string& s, const string& w);

        bool runSchedule(string myinfile, string myoutfile);

private:
        int totWaitTime;
        int totTurnAround;
        int timeElapsed;
        int vectorSize;
        vector <Process> arrivedProc;


};

#endif // FCFS_H_INCLUDE
```

My .cpp file:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <sstream>

    #include <Process.h>
    #include "FCFS.h"

    using namespace std;

    void FCFS::buildMatrix(ifstream& myinfile){
            string line;
            while(getline(myinfile, line)){
                    Process newProc = buildProcess(line);
                    arrivedProc.push_back(newProc);
            }

            sort(arrivedProc.begin(), arrivedProc.end(), Process::compareAT);
            vectorSize = arrivedProc.size();
    }

    vector<string> FCFS::parser (const string& s, const string& w){
            string temp{s};
            for (char& ch : temp){
                    for (char white : w){
                            if (ch == white) ch = ' ';
                    }
            }

            vector <string> substrings;
            stringstream ss;
            ss << temp;
            for (string buffer; ss >> buffer;){
                    substrings.push_back(buffer);
            }

            return substrings;
    }

    Process FCFS::buildProcess(string line){
            vector<string> procEl = parser(line, ",-");
            Process newProc(stoi(procEl[0]), stoi(procEl[1]), 

stoi(procEl[2]), stoi(procEl[3]), stoi(procEl[4]), stoi(procEl[5]));
                return newProc;
        }
    bool FCFS::runSchedule(string myin, string myout){
...just implempentation that I don't think is the problem...
    }

int main(){
        FCFS sched;
        string in = "Sample_Input1.txt";
        string out = "output.txt";

        sched.runSchedule(in, out);
}
```

my error:

```
    Ethans-MacBook-Pro:HW4 lozae$ g++ -g -Wall -std=c++11 -I. FCFS.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Process::setWT(double)", referenced from:
      FCFS::runSchedule(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in FCFS-53eb8f.o
  "Process::setTAT(double)", referenced from:
      FCFS::runSchedule(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in FCFS-53eb8f.o
  "Process::print(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const", referenced from:
      FCFS::runSchedule(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in FCFS-53eb8f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What is your linker command line?

Comment: What is `Process`? If it is what you wrote, check for typo. If it is external library, link required things.

Comment: "...just implempentation that I don't think is the problem..." And that's exactly where the problem is. Edit your post, and provide a [mcve]. What do you think the "referenced from: FCFS::runSchedule" is talking about? The compiler is telling you where the problem is, and somehow you decided that this is not where the problem is. Strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either there is a problem compiling the code for `Process`, which you did not include, or you didn't tell g++ where to find the library to link to.

An "Undefined Symbol" type error means that the linker cannot find the compiled code for a symbol. (In this case `Process::setWT`, `Process::setTAT`, and `Process::print`.) You need to tell g++ where to find the libraries to link to.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

A brief overview of how code compiles with g++ is: 1) `g++` **compiles** the code into **object files** and/or **libraries**, 2) `ld` (the linker) **links** the **object files** and **libraries** into an executable.

This is simplified, but it is important to know that the **linker** needs to know what **object files** and **libraries** (compiled code, but not executables) to *link* together to create the **executable** file.

Comment: This post may also prove helpful.
[Undefined Symbols for architecture x86_64: Compiling problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751868/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-compiling-problems)

Comment: Thank you guys so much! That link seemed to be very helpful and I was able to solve my localized issue along with my greater undefined issue problem. There was a typo in the line that linked all of the .cpp files together.